# How to Wrap Each Widget with Getx obx Shows Improper use of Getx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am Trying to do Draggable ListView Builder and the Listview builder is wrapped with getx obx after that i wrapped the listview with draggablescrollsheet when i run the code it show error..
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

This error means you are using `Obx()` on the top of a widget tree that doesn't contains any `.obs` variables and are not going to update. In other words, your `cart` is not observable variable.

The solution would be to make `cart` variable observable. You can make any variable observable using a simple ".obs" in the end, like

```
var cart = YourModel().obs;
```

Comment: final cartListController = Get.put(CartListController()).obs; are saying about this

Comment: Nope, inside your CartListController there is a variable named cart, make it .obs

Comment: its already in .obs

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uEASEi05

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eiUkWvcK